# The best way to design this basic SQL table example?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Let's say I have some products, 2-3k max.
each product has a list of users related to it 1-2k max.

Being a begginer in SQL, I have 2 ideas that come in mind:

1) Each product as a csv style(comma-separated values) list of users.
So I will have `N (num of products)` rows, each one with `M (num of users)`
that I will parse in php.

2) 1 row for each product - user.
So I will have a much longer (in term of rows) table.

Example with 1 product.

```
1 | product1 | {1,2,3,....,M}
.
.
N | productN | {3,1,66,...,M'}
```

---

Example with 2 products.

```
1 | product1 | 1
2 | product1 | 8
.
.
X | productY | Z
```

I prefer the 1. idea, but I was told that 2. is how we do it.
What are the other possibilities?
What is the right one?

Comment: WHat are you asking for exactly? How to set up the database in a neat normalised way, or how to import it?

Comment: 2 is the right one. Using 1 will most likely cause all kinds of problems down the road.

Comment: Imagine you want to select all products assigned to a certain user. If you use option 2, the query is as simple as `SELECT product FROM product_users WHERE user = 1`. If you use option 1, suddenly even a simple thing like this is much more difficult.

Comment: Many-to-Many. Shouldn't this be done with 3 tables?

Comment: @FirstOne I think this IS the third table.

Comment: Oh sorry. If that's the case @Don'tPanic, I should just mention that there is no need to save the name of the product in the 3rd table... Referring the `ID` is the way to go ^^.. I still suggest to **the OP to read about this type of relationship**

Comment: @FirstOne I suppose I don't know for sure if that is the case. And I do agree about saving the ID.

Comment: This an opinion-seeking question with no single right answer. It's off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: @Don'tPanic - there is no right answer. And answering in comments makes no sense.  Comments are for clarification purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Thank you all, it helped me.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic "normalisation״ question. There are different approaches to this, ranging from no-normalisation (your 2nd option) to complete normalisation which would mean you'd have another table in the middle, with only, connecting the 2 entities you've mentioned (products, users).

The correct answer depends on the problem you wish to solve, and the logical relation between the 2 entities - 1 to 1, 1 to N, N to N.

I'm imagining it could be possible that users and products are independent from each other (Many to Many). Meaning, there are users that can have different products, and products that can have different users. Hence I think the best solution for you would be full normalisation, meaning - Keep a table for each type of entity, and make sure you have a key column for each row. Then have a connection table that is made of 2 rows, representing the keys of each entity. Each row in that table would represent a link between a product to a user.

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

I would say number 2 with the following motivation:

If you create indexes for both the product and the user the second example will perform much better since you will lose the overhead of having to expand an array and checking it's content.

If you were to use a JSON based database like mongoDB I would suggest using number 1 since it would not create the same overhead when expanding a value vs looking through all the other rows.